# Calculating energy of a spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring, elasticity

A toy of mass 20g attached to a spring is compressed and when the toy is released it jumps 0.7 m into the air. Calculate the energy of the spring. Assume the limit of proportionality is not exceeded.

The solutions state that the elastic potential energy is equivalent to the gravitational potential energy assuming no energy is lost. They then use the formula $mgh$ to find the energy of the spring.

To me this doesn't make any sense. What's going on?

Comment: At first the system only has the elastic potential energy (EPE) as the spring is compressed. When it is released, over a short time period, the EPE is converted to a mix of EPE and kinetic energy (KE) (and a little gravitational potential energy (GPE)), and finally assumed to just be KE and GPE, and finally only purely GPE. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The system comprising the toy, spring and the Earth is (assumed) isolated, so:
$$\Delta K + \Delta U = 0 \rightarrow \Delta K + \Delta U_s + \Delta U_g = 0$$

where $U_s$ denotes elastic potential energy of the spring, and $U_g$ denotes gravitational potential energy of the system (primarily between the toy and Earth)

So if the initial condition is just before it was released,
$$i: \text{Just before release} : K_i = 0, U_{si} \ne 0, U_g = mgy_i$$

Take the final condition to be when the toy is at it's maximum height (where it's speed is zero), and we get:
$$f: \text{The toy is at its maximum height} : K_f = 0, U_{si} = 0, U_g = mgy_f$$
Then the equation gives:
$$(0-0) + (0 -U_{si}) + (mg(y_f - y_i)) = 0$$ which rearranges to:
$$\boxed{U_{si} = mg(y_f - y_i) \equiv mgh \ni h = y_f - y_i}$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This scenario displayed the law of energy conservation. The spring was compressed and stored elastic potential energy as $\tfrac 1 2kx^2$. After the spring is released, all the energy was transferred to the toy (as the spring “relaxes”). The energy carries the toy to a height until gravity decelerates it to a halt. Now the toy is at a height from the ground with no kinetic energy and no elastic potential energy. The toy is some distance from the ground, so the energy is stored as gravitational potential energy. Then you know that all the elastic potential energy is converted into gravitational potential energy, and the initial elastic potential energy and final gravitational potential energy have the same value.

Energy conversion stages: $\tfrac 1 2kx^2$ (elastic potential energy) —> $\tfrac 1 2mv^2 + mgh$ (at this stage the energy conversion is constantly taking place) —> $mgh$ (gravitational potential energy)